# Why is my icing still going inside my doughnut even after I enabled snapping

Tags: edit-mode

I have enabled snapping but it still does not work.
[image]

I tried to increase the distance between the Icing and Doughnut but It did not work. And after I switched back from object mode to Edit mode the Icing goes missing.
[image]

Comment: maybe unhide (atl H) when you are in Edit mode? Also, the icing faces may go through some of the donut faces if your icing is low-poly

Comment: Yea alt H makes the doughnut appear but it does not stop the icing from going inside the doughnut even tough snapping is enabled. Thnx for alt H

Comment: As I said if your icing is very low-poly, some parts of your faces may cross the surface of the donut underneath, so you can add a bit of topology if you really don't want this problem

Comment: Thank You problem got solved

Answer (score 0):

Unhide (<kbd>Atl</kbd><kbd>H</kbd>) when you are in *Edit* mode. Also, your icing is very low-poly, some parts of your faces may cross the surface of the donut underneath, so you can add a bit of topology, for example select all and right click > *Subdivide*.